# Swift POST request and activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, uiactivityindicatorview, swifty-json

Hello I am using SwiftyJSON library to fetch data from server. My code is following :

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let message2  = "Please wait..."
    var messageMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    messageMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message2 as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",size: 15.0)!])
    alert.setValue(messageMutableString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();



    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Global.ipAdres)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = Global.postString
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {                                                   data, response, error in


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.printNameSurname()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return;
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
        {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }            
        let json = JSON(data)

        GlobalVariable.nameSurname = json["data"]["nameSurname"].stringValue + json["data"]["sad"].stringValue
        GlobalVariable.id = json["data"]["id"].stringValue
        GlobalVariable.id2 = json["data"]["id2"].stringValue

    }
    task.resume()
```

If I do not understand wrong my printNameSurname() function needs to be execute  and fill two of labels in my view controller  my activity indicator should be dismissed when I got the values and  that's why I put it in Dispatch.main.async. However, they are not working correctly. My labels are not filling with data that I fetched. I think the problem is about post request but I have searched examples of it but they are not working for me or I am doing something wrong how can I fix it ?

Comment: `self.printNameSurname()` is called before `GlobalVariable.nameSurname = ...` Is that normal? Should you put `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.printNameSurname(); self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}` after?

Comment: It is now working after put my code as you described place thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Just put all code in main queue after got response as below.

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {                                                   data, response, error in

        //Trick here...
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.printNameSurname()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return;
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
            {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }
            let json = JSON(data)

            GlobalVariable.nameSurname = json["data"]["nameSurname"].stringValue + json["data"]["sad"].stringValue
            GlobalVariable.id = json["data"]["id"].stringValue
            GlobalVariable.id2 = json["data"]["id2"].stringValue
        }

    }
```